# Check if object exists - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, object

Instead of recreating an object over and over again, is there a way I can check if an object exists in an if statement?

Thanks!

Comment: You must mean something beyond "if (o != nil) { ... }" right?

Comment: I was just looking for the best way to do it and the answerers below showed me a very easy way!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming your object reference is set to `nil` if there is no object, then you can use

```
NSThing *myobj = nil;

if (!myobj)
    myobj = [[NSThing alloc] init];
[myobj message];
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your situation. You could use a static variable, i.e.

```
- (void) doSomething
{
    static id foo = nil;
    if (! foo)
        foo = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    // Do something with foo.
}
```

The first time -doSomething gets called, MyClass will be instantiated. Note that this isn't thread-safe.

Another way is to use a singleton. Possibly a better way is to instantiate the object when the application has finished launching and pass the object to any other objects that might need it.

Answer (score 1):

The thread safe common way to initialize some instance using GCD is as follows:

```
static dispatch_once_t once;
dispatch_once(&once, ^{
    obj = [NSSomeThing new];
});
```